# how to make container responsive when device change?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have created a div, and give it an initial size, css as below, I want it can responsive in different devices.

```
.main {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-family: museo_sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Lucida Grande,sans-serif;
  width: 30em;
  height: 40em;
  background-color: tomato;
  border: solid 1px black;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto
}
```

[demo result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0BFM.png)

What I want is make it responsive, when view in different device.
Similar as a component in Airtasker website, in the browser, it has its initial size (width and heigth) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGRWO.png)

but when viewed on different device, or just zoom out browser, it will auto-scale to fit the screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSBal.png)

I know the solution may be very simple, but I just don't understand how to do it.

Comment: You need to share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in many ways, and two most common would probably be:

- setting its width to some percentage value (like 80%) and some fixed `max-width` value. This way it will take 80% of the screen on smaller devices, but won't be bigger than the fixed value you specified on bigger screens;

```css
.modal {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 50rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

- using [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media), where you will have exact control over how elements behave under certain conditions (screen size most commonly).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that really solve parts of my puzzle. May I bother you again, what about height? Can I also give height a max-value, and when in smaller screen, it will fix the screen size. I try to do that, but the div becomes a line

Comment: Don't worry, I figure it up, set min-height instead of max-height, anyway, thank you again!